# How the function will behave in case of difference in no. of arguments passed and no. of arguments defined in the function definition in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm a newbie to PHP. I've a following function call:

```
UpdateUserTestStatus($user_id, $user_test['test_user_test_id'], $user_test['test_user_start_time'], $user_test_time);
```

The definition of function is as follows:

```
function UpdateUserTestStatus($user_id, $test_id, $user_test_start_time, $user_test_time, $test_pack_id) { 
        if($user_id!='' && $test_id!='') {
            $sql  = " UPDATE ".TBL_TESTS_USERS." SET test_user_status='present', ";
            $sql .= " test_user_start_time=".$user_test_start_time.", test_user_time_used=".$user_test_time;
            $sql .= " WHERE test_user_user_id='".$user_id."' AND test_user_test_id=".$test_id;
            $sql .= " AND test_pack_id='".$test_pack_id."' ";

            $this->mDb->Query($sql);

            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
```

So my question is, does that work in PHP having different no. of arguments in function call and having different no. of arguments present in the function definition? Please guide me in this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If there are **less arguments in the definition** than in the call, the excess arguments will simply be ignored.

If there are **less arguments in the call** than in the definition, the missing arguments will be set to `null` and a warning will be issued.

Comment: Thanks for your help @AndreKR. Please tell me that in case of my function what will be the value of variable $test_pack_id after making the function call? My next doubt is will the Update query get execute in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, it will be executed and `$test_pack_id` will be `null`, which - cast to string - will be an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give arguments default values if they are optional. For example:

```
function full_name($firstname, $lastname, $middlenames = NULL) {
    $name = $firstname;
    if ($middlenames !== NULL) {
        $name .= ' '.$middlenames;
    }
    $name .= ' '.$lastname;
    return $name;
}
echo full_name('John', 'Doe'); // John Doe
echo full_name('John', 'Doe', 'Smith'); // John Smith Doe
echo full_name('John'); // Warning!
```

If you do not give optional arguments default values then you will get a warning when you do not use the argument.